Downloading the file created from the SQL query - BLAZOR SERVER
I have a file that creates a *.csv file on the server in the C:\backup path. The file is created using an SQL query to the database. I would like to attach a button that will allow me to create a file and download it at the same time.
A method that creates a file on the server:
    public void erxporttoExcelMO(int mg, string mag)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(con))
        {

            connection.Open();
           
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            string exportPath = @"C:\backup\magazyn_okuc\";
            string exportCsv = "MagazynOkuc.csv";
            string filepath = exportPath + exportCsv;
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                File.Delete(filepath);
            }
          //  string exportCsv = "MagazynOkuc"+mag+ "-" + today.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".csv";
            StreamWriter csvFile = null;
            var sql = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY om.indeks ) as row_number, om.indeks,om.nazwa,p.jednostka,om.data_zalozenia,om.data_lastmodf,(p.ilosc - CASE WHEN(SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer )END) as ilosc,(CASE WHEN(SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer )END) as ilosc_zarez,r.opis as regal,p.polka,p.stan, p.uwagi,CASE WHEN (SUM(t.TwZ_Ilosc) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE ROUND(SUM(t.TwZ_Ilosc),2) END AS ERPXL,  CASE WHEN p.minimal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE p.minimal END AS minimal, CASE WHEN p.Przydas IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE p.Przydas END AS przydas, CASE WHEN p.opty_wykluczenie IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE p.opty_wykluczenie END AS opty_wykluczenie, ((SELECT SUM(pp.ilosc) FROM CompositeApps.dbo.mg_okucia_polozenie pp WHERE pp.gid_numer = p.gid_numer AND p.Magazyn = "+mg+")- (CASE WHEN(SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer ) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT SUM(r1.ilosc)  FROM CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje r1 WHERE r1.gid_numer =p.gid_numer )END) ) AS suma_ilosci, m.skrot FROM okucia_magazyn om  JOIN mg_okucia_polozenie p ON p.gid_numer = om.gid_numer JOIN mg_regaly r on r.id = p.regal LEFT JOIN [ERPXL_VIKKING].[CDN].[TwrZasoby] t on om.gid_numer = t.TwZ_TwrNumer LEFT JOIN CompositeApps.dbo.rezerwacje rr ON rr.gid_numer = om.gid_numer JOIN CompositeApps.dbo.MagazynyID m ON m.id= p.magazyn WHERE p.magazyn = "+mg +"  GROUP BY om.gid_numer,om.indeks,om.nazwa,om.id,p.jednostka,om.data_zalozenia,om.data_lastmodf,p.ilosc,r.opis,p.polka,p.stan,p.uwagi ,rr.ilosc, p.gid_numer, p.minimal,p.Przydas ,p.opty_wykluczenie, r.id, p.magazyn,m.skrot  ORDER BY om.indeks ASC";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            csvFile = new StreamWriter(@exportPath + exportCsv,true, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            csvFile.WriteLine(String.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"," +
                    "\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\",\"{10}\",\"{11}\",\"{12}\",\"{13}\",\"{14}\",\"{15}\",\"{16}\",\"{17}\"",
                reader.GetName(0), reader.GetName(1), reader.GetName(2),
             reader.GetName(3), reader.GetName(4), reader.GetName(5), reader.GetName(6), reader.GetName(7), reader.GetName(8), reader.GetName(9), reader.GetName(10), reader.GetName(11), reader.GetName(12), reader.GetName(13), reader.GetName(14), reader.GetName(15), reader.GetName(16), reader.GetName(17)));
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                csvFile.WriteLine(String.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"," +
                                      "\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\",\"{10}\",\"{11}\",\"{12}\",\"{13}\",\"{14}\",\"{15}\",\"{16}\",\"{17}\"",
                                      reader[0], reader[1], reader[2], reader[3], reader[4], reader[5], reader[6], reader[7], reader[8], reader[9], reader[10], reader[11], reader[12], reader[13], reader[14], reader[15], reader[16], reader[17]));

            }
            csvFile.Close();
}

Now I don't know what to do with him next. Additionally, the date is added and it is best to download the latest file.
Any tips?

Topic to be closed. I found the solution myself.

You could maybe share your solution so someone else with a similar question would benefit from your research ? Otherwise, you can cleanup yourself, there should be a "delete" button underneath your question.

You know what, it doesn't work as expected because from time to time I get an error while downloading that the process is in use and the file cannot be downloaded.
